# Prove $L(x) = \ln x$ if $L(xy)=L(x)+(y)$ and $\lim \limits_{t \to 0}(\frac{L(1+t)}{t})=1 $

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $L:(0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that
>
> $$L(xy)=L(x)+(y)$$ and $$\lim \limits_{t \to 0}\frac{L(1+t)}{t}=1 $$
>
> Prove that $L(x)=\ln x$ for every $x>0$.

I was able to prove that $L(1)=0$ with the first identity, but I don't know how to use the second one to prove that the derivative of $L(x)$ is $1/x$.

[edit]
so far I got that the derivative:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{L(x+h)-L(x)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{L(1+\frac{h}{x})}{h}$$

and then im doing circles, I got that that is equal to

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{L(\frac{1}{h}+\frac{1}{x})+L(h)+L(x)+L(\frac{1}{x})}{h}$$

but I don't see how this could get me anywhere, while I can't take a literal $x$ out of a $L$ function

Answer (score 4):

Hint: We have that
$$L(x)+L(1/x)=L(1)=0$$
Which means that
$$L(x+h)-L(x)=L\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)$$
And the derivative of $L$ at $x$ is
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{L(x+h)-L(x)}{h}$$
Edit: Can you calculate the following limit?
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{L\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)}{\frac{h}{x}}$$

Comment: I can't do it, for more that I move, I don't see how to factor out a "x" out of the limit, I can see how you get "1", but I don't understand how to get the "x"

Comment: @rorod8 $x$ is independent of $h$, so you can "bring it outside".

Comment: @rorod8 If you are still stuck, please add your own work to your question with an edit, so we can see it and direct you in the right direction :)

Comment: I did it, please help :(

Comment: @rorod8 I added something to my answer.

Comment: yes I see, with that limit you get 1/x, so you can add an x under the h because it's basically 0?

Comment: nevermind, I see, you changed variables, or something like that, because h/x => 0 as well

Comment: @rorod8 You can do it because for a fixed nonzero $x$, $\frac{h}{x} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: @rorod8 Yes, exactly!

Comment: then you place it like 1/(the reciprocal of the limit) so you get 1/(1*x), right?

Comment: @rorod8 What do you mean exactly?